# Синхронная очередь задач Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

Нужно создать несколько задач относящихся к одной группе, например она называется `"Дом"`.
Но нужно чтобы назначенные задачи, например `"мытьё пола"`, `"починка мебели"` и `"замена лампочки"` выполнялись только по очереди. Нельзя чтобы они выполнялись одновременно.

Предположим пользователь выбирает:

```
 1. Помыть пол в гостинной.
 2. Заменить лампочку в ванной
 3. Помыть пол на кухне
 4. Починить шкаф в коридоре
 5. Помыть пол в коридоре
```

И нужно, чтобы эти задачи последовательно. Может даже не в порядке нумерации, но главное не параллельно.
Celery уже работает в несколько воркеров, поэтому запускать его в один не вариант.

Используется связка `django, celery, redis`.

Comment: Пример какой-то не очень удачный, в реальной жизни эти задачи прекрасно выполняются параллельно)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно стоит попробовать использовать цепочки(Chains), подробнее здесь:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553620/does-a-celery-chain-execute-tasks-in-a-specific-order

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901101/pythoncelery-chaining-jobs